# Understanding being closed under addition and multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having serious trouble trying to figure out this whole, "being closed under addition and scalar multiplication"

Our example is

Let $W=\{[a,b,c]:a+b=4c;b=2c\}$

I need to figure out if it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, I am not sure how to do this though.. 
do I just add $a+b=4c$ and $b=2c$ together?

If you could help explain this to me, I'll greatly appreciate it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your space $W$ consists of elements $[a,b,c]$ such that $a+b=4c$ and $b=2c$.

To show this is closed under addition take two elements of $W$, say $[a_1, b_1, c_1]$ and $[a_2, b_2, c_2]$ and show the sum $[a_1, b_1, c_1] + [a_2, b_2, c_2] = [a_1 + a_2, b_1 + b_2, c_1 + c_2]$ lies in $W$, i.e. that $(a_1 + a_2) + (b_1 + b_2) = 4(c_1 + c_2)$ and $(b_1 + b_2) = 2(c_1 + c_2)$.

For scalar multiplication you need to take an element of $W$, $[a,b,c]$, and a scalar, $\lambda$ and show $\lambda[a,b,c] = [\lambda a, \lambda b, \lambda c]$ lies in $W$.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on WMycroft's example, consider some more intuitive examples:

(1) The set of even numbers is additively-closed under itself since adding two even numbers always produces an even number. On the other hand, the set of odd-numbers is not additively-closed under itself since 1 + 3 = 4 and 4 is not odd but even.

(2) We say that the integers do not form a group under addition because there does not exist any integer $x$ such that $4*x = 1$ since the solution to that equation is $x = \dfrac{1}{4} \not \in \mathbb{Z}$. 1

(3) More generally, one can say that a set $S$ with a binary operation $R: S \times S \rightarrow S$ is closed over $S$ if for any $a,b \in S$, $a R b \in S$.

Answer (score 1):

in this case a simplification is possible we have $a+b=4c$ and $b=2c$ so $a=2c$. hence 
$$
W = \{[2c,2c,c]\} = \{c\xi\}
$$
where the vector $\xi=[2,2,1]$ and $c$ is any scalar

now if $w_1\xi,w_2\xi \in W$ for scalars $w_1,w_2$ we have
$$
w_1 \xi + w_2 \xi = (w_1+w_2)\xi
$$
and the vector on the RHS is in $W$ because $w_1+w_2$ is a scalar

similarly if $\lambda$ is a scalar then
$$
\lambda(w_1\xi) = (\lambda w_1)\xi
$$
and since $\lambda w_1$ is also a scalar, the vector on the right-hand side is in $W$.

so $W$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. it is, in fact, a one-dimensional subspace.